# How To set Shadow(Light) using DirectioalLight on boxgeometry in threejs?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, shadow, light

I am used Directionl light for shadow, But I need Light shadow not Dark. I am using this code : -

```
   this.root.remove(this.light.shadow.camera);    
   this.scene.remove(this.light);
   this.scene.remove(this.camera);
   this.light.position.set(0, minPosition, maxPosition);    
   this.light.castShadow = true;
   this.light.intensity = 1.6;
   this.light.shadow.camera.top = 16; // default
   this.light.shadow.camera.bottom = -6; // default
   this.light.shadow.camera.right = 10; // default
   this.light.shadow.camera.left = -10; // default
   cube.castShadow = true;
   this.light.shadow.transparent = true;
   this.light.target.position.add(this.scene.position);
   this.light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
 this.light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
```

[![BoxShadow][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/00byW.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Hemishpere light " over the "Directional light" which will reduce the shadow intensity. You can refer to the three.js examples :
https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_exporter_ply